# Storing element in array that's a pointer

Tags: c++, arduino

I'd like to store an element in an array, the as parameter given array is a pointer to the real array (to prevent unnecessarily copying data).

```
bool storeElementToArray(sensor element, sensor *sensors) {
  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(sensors) / sizeof(element) - 1); i++) {
    if (!sensors[i].getIsObject()) { // Check if the current element is already a "real" sensor or just a reserved part of memory to store a a sensor
      helper::debug(F("Stored at index "), false ,false);
      helper::debugInt(i, true, false);
      sensors[i] = element;
      break;
    }
  }
}

sensor sensors[5];
```

I want to store `element` to `sensors` while `sensors` should only be a pointer / reference to the array `sensors[5]` because I need to specify which array the element should be stored to. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The `sizeof` of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to. When you need to pass an "array" to a function, always include the size as an argument.

Comment: Good point, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A "pointer/reference" to an array seems to point out some issues in understanding how pointers work in relation to arrays.

When you take a pointer to an array element, and "pass an array" to such function, you're triggering array-to-pointer decay, and what you end up passing is the pointer to the first element.

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int* p) {
    std::cout << p << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int arr[5];

    // both are exactly the same
    f(arr); 
    f(&arr[0]);
}
```

Thus, in your case, passing `sensors` via `sensor*` will work, and you'll be able to change the contents of the array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void set(int val, int ix, int* storage) {
    storage[ix] = val;
}

int main() {
    int values[10];
    std::fill(std::begin(values), std::end(values), 0);

    set(42, 3, values);

    for (auto v : values) {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

That being said, if you're passing an array, you need some way to assess the size to avoid out-of-bounds access; one way to do that is to pass it as another parameter.

That being said, it's much preferrable to use `std::array`, which you can then pass as a reference. That way you avoid all the pointer shenanigans and get the size passed automatically. The downside is that you need to know the size at compile-time.

Unfortunately, while providing `std::string_view`, C++ lacks builtin memory-view primitive. `std::vector` is used in desktop code, but its use in embedded program for a limited MCU is rather questionable. In that case, you might need/want to write your own type encompassing the pointer and size, e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
struct ArrayView {
    T* ptr;
    std::size_t sz;
public:
    template<int arrSize>
    ArrayView(T (&arr)[arrSize]) : ptr(arr), sz(arrSize) { }

    T& operator[](int i) { return ptr[i]; }
    std::size_t size() const { return sz; }
};
```